# Hadoop Hive XPaths return only part of the array

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, xquery

I am using Hadoop Hive and trying to process XML file. The file looks like this:

```
<asds4_0:SASDS>
<stl15:GetRS>
    <stl15:RS>
        <stl15:ORES>
            <stl15:ORE>
                <stl15:AccF>
                    <stl15:Transaction>
                        <stl15:Status>Hold</stl15:Status>
                    </stl15:Transaction>
                </stl15:AccF>
            </stl15:ORE>
            <stl15:ORE>
                <stl15:AccF>
                    <stl15:Transaction>
                        <stl15:Status>Active</stl15:Status>
                    </stl15:Transaction>
                </stl15:AccF>
            </stl15:ORE>
        </stl15:ORES>
    </stl15:RS>
</stl15:GetRS>
</asds4_0:SASDS>
```

The xpath I am using to retrieve the status is :

```
SELECT
Status
FROM scenario1
LATERAL VIEW explode(xpath(cast(body as string),"//*[local-name()='SASDS']//*[local-name()='GetRS']//*[local-name()='RS']//*[local-name()='ORES']//*[local-name()='ORE']//*[local-name()='AccF']//*[local-name()='Transaction']//*[local-name()='Status']/text()")) adTable as Status
```

This xpath returns both statuses Active and Hold. The problem is that I want to retrieve only status Active.
 I try to use something like this [[local-name()='Status']='Active'] (like it is shown here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) I still get the two records Hold and Active.

I don't want to use WHERE Status='Active' in the sql because it does not return the desired rows when I combine this with other fields.

Comment: obligatory comment on your resource: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Answer (score 0):

First of, is there any specific reason why you use a construct like

```
*[local-name()='SASDS']
```

all over the place? it is equivalent (but way less readable) to

```
*:SASDS
```

Additionally, you use `//*` everywhere, which returns and searches for all descendant elements. But given your XML structure, you normally just want to access the immediate child, so it is again more readable (and faster) to just search for the child using `/`.

So, better would be:

```
*:SASDS/*:GetRS/*:RS/*:ORES/*:ORE/*:AccF/*:Transaction/*:Status[. = "Active"]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Dirkk's solution but, as you may have already discovered, it isn't going to work for you.  One of the many limitations of the builtin XML support in Hive is that it is based on XPath 1.0.

But, you could use his solution with the Oracle XML Extensions for Hive:
http://docs.oracle.com/bigdata/bda49/BDCUG/oxh_hive.htm#BDCUG691

It is part of Oracle XQuery for Hadoop which can be downloaded here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/bdc/big-data-connectors/downloads/index.html

Examples:

```
  SELECT xml_query_as_string(
    "*:SASDS/*:GetRS/*:RS/*:ORES/*:ORE/*:AccF/*:Transaction/*:Status[. = 'Active']", 
    body
  ) 
  FROM scenario1;
```

Will return: "Active"

There is also a table function:

```
  SELECT t.status
  FROM scenario1 LATERAL VIEW xml_table(
    '*:SASDS/*:GetRS/*:RS/*:ORES/*:ORE/*:AccF/*:Transaction', 
    body, 
    struct ('*:Status')
  ) t as status
  WHERE t.status = 'Active';
```

And good namespace support if you want to ditch the wildcards:

```
SELECT t.status
FROM scenario1 LATERAL VIEW xml_table(
  struct(
    'stl15', 'http://example.org/ns1',
    'asds4_0', 'http://example.org/ns2'
  ),
  'asds4_0:SASDS/stl15:GetRS/stl15:RS/stl15:ORES/stl15:ORE/stl15:AccF/stl15:Transaction', 
  body, 
  struct ('stl15:Status')
) t as status
WHERE t.status = 'Active';
```